# Can't use the "this" keyword to access data in the Vuejs data/method/lifeCycle instances

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working on adding a pagination feature to a listing page but that's not the issue. The issue is that each time i try to use the `this` keyword to get the property value of the data instance, i get the value of `undefined` like `console.log("object=======>", this.currentPage); // undefined` inside getPageToShow() method and the `disable: this.currentPage === 1` inside the data instance itself seems not to be returning the expected value. But i can access all these data properties values within the template.

I have tried to use `created` and `mounted` lifecycle instance just to confirm that the component is not rendering before the data get bind, all to no avail.

Here is my code;

```
export default {
    name: "Pagination",
    data() {
        return {
            pageToShow: this.getPageToShow(),
            currentPage: null,
            disable: this.currentPage === 1
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.currentPage = this.$store.state.currentPage;
    },
    methods: {
        getPageToShow(num) {
            console.log("object=======>", this.currentPage, this.disable);
            this.$store.commit(Types.UPDATE_PAGETOSHOW, num);
            return this.$store.state.pageToShow;
        }
    }
};
```

This is how I'm using the data in my template and is working fine.

```html
<template>
 <div>
  <button
    class="fl dib link dim black f5 b pa2 bg-white ba bw0"
    :style="disable && { cursor: 'not-allowed' }"
    title="Previous"
    :disabled="disable"
    tabindex="-1"
  >
    &larr; Previous
  </button>
 </div>
</template>
```

I have tried to `console.log(this)` of which i can see those properties inside there but `this` keyword seems not to be fetching them inside the Vue instances. I want e.g `console.log("object=======>", this.currentPage, this.disable)` to return the actual value not `// undefined, undefined`. Thanks

Comment: Are you properly registering your VueX plugin? If you hard-code the value for `currentPage`, do you still get `undefined`?

Comment: You should use a `computed` property to get the state value through a getter: `this.$store.getters.currentPage`.

Comment: @TommyF thanks, I have done that before and it works just fine ... But i still have to be calling the store each time i needed the `currentPage` value instead of calling the property in the data instance. What do you think?

Comment: @Mindsworth the `computed` property will always be up to date and in sync with the store, Vue takes care of that.